# Calling .env variables in a JS script in a Django template

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have my following credentials stored in a `.env` file:

```
#Google Drive API
GOOGLE_DRIVE_API_KEY='XX'
GOOGLE_DRIVE_API_CLIENT_ID='XX.apps.googleusercontent.com'
GOOGLE_DRIVE_APP_ID='XX'
```

In my Django template, I would like to call these variables to initiate the Google Drive File Picker:

```
<script>
    var API_KEY = 'xx';
    var CLIENT_ID = 'xx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    var APP_ID = 'xx';

    // Scope to use to access user's Drive items.
    var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
</script>
```

Since it's absolutely not secure to put these credentials directly inside the JS script, do you know how I can call these credentials (like `os.getenv()` in Python)?

Comment: An alternative solution would be to load these env variables in your views.py and pass it to the template file.

Comment: @SauravPanda I tried this solution but API keys are still shown when I check the source code from my browser.

Comment: The issue is you are trying to use API keys on the client side. It's usually vulnerable as people can read the client-side code. Usually, it's a good practice not to use keys on the client side. Also, why are you using API_KEY? At a quick glance, I think the google drive file picker only needs the client Id and scope, which are okay to be visible.

Comment: Within the function `createPicker()`, for `setDeveloperKey`, I actually need the API Key.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access *environment variables* in JS, but you can achieve it using JSON response (NOT TESTED):

1. Fix the `.env` values (remove quotes)

```
GOOGLE_DRIVE_API_KEY=XX
GOOGLE_DRIVE_API_CLIENT_ID=XX.apps.googleusercontent.com
GOOGLE_DRIVE_APP_ID=XX
```

2. views.py:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_google_drive_credentials(request):
    # Load the .env file
    load_dotenv()  

    # Get the values
    google_drive_api_key = os.getenv('GOOGLE_DRIVE_API_KEY')
    google_drive_api_client_id = os.getenv('GOOGLE_DRIVE_API_CLIENT_ID')
    google_drive_app_id = os.getenv('GOOGLE_DRIVE_APP_ID')
    
    # Create a JSON response
    data = {
        'api_key': google_drive_api_key,
        'client_id': google_drive_api_client_id,
        'app_id': google_drive_app_id,
    }
    
    # Return the response
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

3. index.html:

```
<script>
    // Make AJAX request to retrieve environment variable values
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                var API_KEY = response.api_key;
                var CLIENT_ID = response.client_id;
                var APP_ID = response.app_id;

                // Scope to use to access user's Drive items.
                var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
            } else {
                console.error('Failed to retrieve Google Drive credentials');
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.open('GET', '/get-google-drive-credentials');
    xhr.send();
</script>
```